# Autopopulated list column with values from another column?

Tags: list, filter, url

Please let me know if there is an easier way to do this..

I am attempting to perform an "OR" filter. I need to able to search a list by either the Title column or the Description column. I'm using the URL to filter the results, but as it is not possible to filter by A OR B, I have the idea of combining my two columns into a single column, and then filtering by that.

It would be hidden in my view - is it still possible to filter by hidden columns?

How do I go about auto-populating a TitleDescription column i.e. TitleDescription = Title + Description.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [Calculated columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx), create your column 'TitleDescription' with 'Calculated Column' as type and use the below formula to concat the Title and Description,

```
=[Title]&[Description]
```

The above code will concat the two column value.

**EDIT:**

Calculated columns in SharePoint 2010 are similar to formulas in Excel spread sheet. Their result is attained by writing formula that uses the values of other columns (their names). You could also check the two links below that show steps of how to achieve a calculated column:

• [SharePoint: Creating Calculated Column Formulas](http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.fi/2010/08/sharepoint-creating-calculated-colu%20mn.html)

• [About SharePoint Calculated Columns](http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/08/07/calculated-columns/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're talking about using the FilterField and FilterValue query string parameters: You can filter on fields that are not displayed in the dataview.

I would actually probably make a seperate querystring parameter for your data view in SP Designer, then you can use an OR condition in the list filter and not make any new fields (you also avoid running in to issues if you don't specify which view the filter applies to)

If you need to create a column that contains the title and description, you would create a new calculated column and use the existing column names to combine the values, like:

```
=[Title]&" "&[Description]
```

A useful list of calculated field formulas is here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx?#Text

Comment: My company does no permit the use a SP Designer. Thanks for answering my question though!

Comment: Uh oh. The description is multi-line, and it seems that it's incompatible with a calculated  column.

Comment: Yeah without Designer access you might need to do something clunky like multiple filterfields, this is a good article on the different things you can do with the filterfield querystring parameter: http://sharepointificate.blogspot.com/2012/12/filtering-listviews-with-url-query.html -- I would bet there is some other way around without using designer (writing your own list view in JavaScript comes to mind) but it may just not be worth the effort in resources.